# How do I seek forgiveness in ramadan?

Tags: sin, tawba

I am a sinner and I need forgiveness.What ayahs should I recite and what is the best way to ask for forgiveness and which time is the best to ask for forgiveness?

Comment: You can add references ive googled a lot and dont understand the right way

Comment: there are many answers for these kinds of questions only on the site I doubt that you've even searched for it.

Answer (score 2):

Similar as in any other time of the year, by repenting sincerely, stopping the sin at once, giving back what is not yours or correcting your mistake towards others (and apologizing and asking them for forgiveness) and trying never to repeat it again.

To seek forgiveness one doesn't need to recite qur'an nor to seek a special hour. Nevertheless it may be good to recite the qur'an and make du'a and dhikr all the time or seek the special hours which the prophet () and the qur'an have indicated us. Such as the hour in the day of Jumu'ah, the 1st third of the night and the time of fajr. But this is for the purpose to do good deeds instead of the sin you've committed in the hope that Allah may accept your repentance.

But, it is never good to waste time if one wants to seek forgiveness. So you should ask for forgiveness once you've come to mind that you've wronged somebody or committed a sin. It is better to repent before you won*t have time to do so!

The only special thing about Ramadan is the worship (and the special night). There are four much more important months in the Muslim Calendar the ashhur al-Hurum الأشهر الحرم (the holy months) Rajab, Dhi-l Qi'da, Dhi-l Hijja and Muharam where the counts for the deeds are multiplied or considered more important/severe (both bad and good deeds). While Ramadan is just one of the eight other (normal) months.

Answer (score 1):

All of us are sinful and incomplete. Our job is to stay away from sins as much as possible and ask for fogiveness always.

In Quran Allah mentioned many prayers of HIS messengers so we can repeat them as per our situation

https://zaahara.com/blogs/writers-corner/selected-verses-of-duas-made-by-prophets-in-quran

Best time of pray is last part of night

At jummah day, between asar and magrib
“Friday is comprised of twelve hours. There is one in which a Muslim who asks Allaah for something will have it granted to him. Seek it in the last hour after `Asr.” [Sunan Abî Dâwûd (1048), Sunan al-Nasâ’î (1389) and Mustadrak al-Hâkim(1032)]
A similar hadîth was related by Anas (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Seek the anticipated hour of Friday after`Asr until sunset” [Sunan al-Tirmidhî (489)] Al-Tirmidh

Comment: I don't see how this answers the actual question at all.

Comment: Your question "which time is the best to ask for forgiveness" Answer is "last part of night" and "jummah day, between asar and magrib".

Comment: Your question: What ayahs should I recite. Answer is Ayah mentioned in the link"https://zaahara.com/blogs/writers-corner/selected-verses-of-duas-made-by-prophets-in-quran". How else should i answer your questions.

Comment: The question is how one seeks forgiveness in Ramadan. Reciting qur'an and seeking special hours has rather nothing to do with this main topic.

Comment: Link is showing the prayers which Prophets of Allah said to get forgiveness. Like Adam (AS) when he was expelled from Paradise he asked for forgiveness links is showing that pray. Younis AS when was in fish belly asked for forgiveness and His pray is in the link. All you need to do is read those prayers and memorise it or just see and pray.

Comment: Special hours are more special in Ramadan, isnt it? Chances of forgiveness are high in special hours when pray in it.

Comment: Ramadan is a normal month there's nothing special about it except what Allah told us we fast it and there's laylat al-Qadr. Anything else needs evidences. It 9s certainly not a holy month. A blog or YouTube is not a source of knowledge.